# Child object doesn't stay relative to parent

Tags: objects, constraints, parent

I've been experiencing trouble when parenting two objects which the child have rotation actuators and lot of constraints. The problem is that on the desert camo plane (VTOL) the engines are supposed to stay in place and rotate on the x axis only. But when I roll the plane left or right the engines rotates at a different speed and dont follow the plane.

Here is the blend file : [link here](http://www.mediafire.com/file/0vv9l1wsi67yojl/Mx+Military+simulator+v77.blend)

Comment: Is this in the BGE?

Comment: im kinda new to coding, in the script i used theres an import bge at the beginning i dunno what it means

Comment: It means Blender Game Engine

Comment: Ok thank you. So yes i made it in blender game engine.